# Some confusing concepts about cache and memory

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-architecture

I am confused with true or false questions about computer caches and memory.
There are 2 questions and my answer for each of them. Could you tell me whether my answer is right or wrong? thanks for reading!

1. Direct mapped cache offers better hit time than set-associative caches.
   my answer: True (Because set associative cache needs more time to search all blocks per set)
2. Fully set-associativity cache does not use index bits during search 
   my answer : True(Because if cache is fully set-associative it only compare the address and cache's tag)

Comment: Yeah, direct-mapped can be a bit faster since even with parallel tag-compare, the muxing to get the right data to the output still has a few more gate delays.  Fully associative has to compare tags for *all* lines; your way of describing it sounds like there's only one comparator.  But yes, it's true; fully-associative is like set associative with all lines as part of the same 1 huge set, thus requiring log2(1) = 0 index bits.